# Jersey and javax.rs - Accepting separate content types

Tags: rest, post, jersey, javax

On my REST API, I've got a POST that did not previously need any input expect from a path parameter. However, I now want to expand by accepting an **optional** form parameter. I tried this out with @FormParam, but it turns out that (at least) one of the clients are not setting content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded, and Jersey fails with this:

> The @FormParam is utilized when the content type of the request entity
>   is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Can I solve this? I want to allow the new clients to send in the form and still accept whatever content type the old clients are setting.

A bad solution would be to use query parameter.

Edit:
Tried adding a new resource with a separate @Consumes

```
@POST
@Path("/something")
@Consumes(MediaType.WILDCARD)
public Response thisDoesNotWork(){
```

and

```
@POST
@Path("/something")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response thisWorks(@FormParam("input") String input){
```

In my tests, when actually sending a form, it works. When I don't send set a content type, it fails with the same error as above. So it seems it selects the thisWorks(..) resource.

Edit2:
I figured out a work-around

```
@POST
@Path("/something")
@Consumes(MediaType.WILDCARD)
public Response thisDoesNotWork(
   MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams
){
```

Using this as the only resource, formParam will be null if no content type is set, and will contain the form parameters if form is set. It will mess up the documentation probably but at least it will work.

Comment: _"I now want to expand by accepting an optional form parameter"_ There's no such thing as _optional_. It's either form parameters or it's not. It's not like you can send JSON and form parameters together. I would just create another resource method that consumes application/x-www-form-urlencoded. This is allowed. You can have two methods with the same HTTP method and same path, as long as the consuming type or producing types are different.

Comment: OK. Thing is, I don't have @Consumes on the resource today as no body was needed. So I guess I have no control of what my client are in fact sending. But I will check it out, I did not know I could have multiple resources with different consumes

Comment: The client does not send a content type, it seems.

Comment: So I can create a new resources accepting x-www-form-urlencoded, but how do I define the resource that must accept requests without content types? Been trying a few variations, without any luck.

Comment: Can you post your code that you tried.

Comment: ok @peeskillet did it now. Also tried it without any Consumes on thisDoesNotWork(), same thing

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? You men you are getting the same error in the doesNotWork even when that method has no @FormParam?

Comment: @peeskillet When I make a call to the API without any content type set, I get the same error "The FormParam is utilized..." as described above. So it seems thisWorks(\@FormParam(..) ..) actually is the method where the request is received, while I want it to be to received by thisDoesNotWork(..) where I don't have any \@FormParam

Comment: But if you set the content-type to anything other than form, then the doesNotWork gets hit?

Comment: @peeskillet Yes.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid using FormParam and instead use Context or another annotation to get the entity, and have logic within the method to check content type etc? @peeskillet

Comment: Posted a solution as Edit2.